# Except, Distinct in MDX

Tags: distinct, mdx, except

Good morning. I'm workin' on a project where i have to calculate the fidelity client kpi. the formula is : (Number of client of year x1 - Number of new client of year x2)/(Number of client of year x1).

So, i have the fact table which contain the foreign key of the degenerate client dimension (PK_Client), im trying this mdx request but it doesn't work :

```
`Nonempty(
        Distinct(
                    EXCEPT(
                        (([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
                        ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].CurrentMember.PrevMember,
                        [Measures].[Remise Facture])),
                        (([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
                        ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].CurrentMember,
                        [Measures].[Remise Facture]))
                        )
                )
       ).Count           
)
/
Nonempty(Distinct([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
     ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].CurrentMember.PrevMember,
      [Measures].[Remise Facture])).Count`
```

i always get 0. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it  :

```
100*(1 -        
Except(
Nonempty(
        Distinct([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
                ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].PrevMember,
                [Measures].[Remise Facture])
     ),
Nonempty(
        Distinct([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
                ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].CurrentMember,
                [Measures].[Remise Facture])
        )).Count
/
Nonempty(
        Distinct([Dim Client].[PK Client].[PK Client]),
                ([Dim Temps 3].[Annee Nom].PrevMember,
                [Measures].[Remise Facture])
        ).Count)
```